# What would stop credentials from validation on a ClearML server?

Tags: clearml

I've set up a ClearML server in GCP using the sub-domain approach. I can access all three domains (`https://app.clearml.mydomain.com`, `https://api.clearml.mydomain.com` and `https://files.clearml.mydomain.com`) in a browser and see what I think is the correct response, but when connecting with the python SDK via `clearml-init` I get the following error:

```
clearml.backend_api.session.session.LoginError: Failed getting token (error 400 from https://api.clearml.mydomain.com): Bad Request
```

Are there any likely causes of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the discussion [here](https://github.com/allegroai/clearml/issues/517), it seemed that the load balancer being used was blocking `GET` requests with a payload which are used by ClearML. A [fix](https://github.com/allegroai/clearml/pull/521) is being worked on to allow the method to be changed to a `POST` request via an environment variable.